# How to use useDocumentData from React Firebase Hook with typed data?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-firebase-hooks

I'm trying to use `useDocumentData` of the [react fire hook library](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master).

I'm struggling a bit on how to retrieve the converted data.

So far, I've this:

```
export const useProfile = () => {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const docRef = doc(db, "profiles", user!.uid);
  useDocumentData<UserProfile>(docRef, {
    snapshotListenOptions: {
      includeMetadataChanges: true,
    },
  });
};
export interface UserProfile {
  propOne: string;
  propTwo: string;
}
```

My issue, is that it says, on the first parameter of `useDocumentData`:

```
Argument of type 'DocumentReference<DocumentData, DocumentData>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference<UserProfile, DocumentData>'.
  Types of property 'converter' are incompatible.
    Type 'FirestoreDataConverter<DocumentData, DocumentData> | null' is not assignable to type 'FirestoreDataConverter<UserProfile, DocumentData> | null'.
      Type 'FirestoreDataConverter<DocumentData, DocumentData>' is not assignable to type 'FirestoreDataConverter<UserProfile, DocumentData>'.
        The types returned by 'fromFirestore(...)' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'DocumentData' is not assignable to type 'UserProfile'.ts(2345)
```

I'm totally aware that I can make a converter to transform data if needed, but in my case, no transformation are required, I've only fields that maps directly to my profile, so to my understanding, it should not be required.

How can I call `useDocumentData` without having this error? Especially if my object doesn't require a conversion?

Comment: If you think the SDK should do something other than what it actually does, maybe you should file an issue on GitHub?  "What am I missing" is a not a straightforward question to answer.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hi, It's not that I think it should do something else, it's that I don't think I should use this for my use case and I don't know what I should use for my use case after reading the doc.

Comment: Then maybe revise your question to be more clear what sort of answer you're looking for?

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry if my question was unclear, you're probably right, I've tried to precise my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because type of `docRef` is `DocumentReference<DocumentData>`, it's not possible to pass it to `useDocumentData<UserProfile>` since type of the first argument is `DocumentReference<UserProfile>`.

So all you need to do is convert `docRef` to `DocumentReference<UserProfile>`.

**1. type casting**

```js
const docRef = doc(db, "profiles", user!.uid) as DocumentReference<UserProfile>;
```

Because your interface is simple, there's little possibility of error, but sometimes it's better to go safer.

**2. FirestoreDataConverter**

You can create custom object that converts from firebase to your own data and reverse.

```js
const converter = {
  toFirestore(doc: UserProfile): DocumentData {
    return doc;
  },
  fromFirestore(snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot): UserProfile {
    return snapshot.data() as UserProfile;
  }
};

// ...

const docRef = doc(db, "profiles", user!.uid).withConverter(converter);
```

This way, you can customize the way firebase convert it's data.

For more information, check this URL: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoredataconverter

Comment: Okay thanks! And just to be sure, the "and reverse" option is only used when calling directly the firestore API, not the react hook fire library?

Comment: Yes you are right.